# How to export files created in device for Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

In Xcode 5 I can export file created in device form `Organizer->Devices->app->Download`, but in Xcode 6 I can't do it the same way.
Then, how to export files created in device for Xcode 6?
Thanks in advance!!!

`How I did in Xcode 5:`
[image: How I did in Xcode 5]

`How I did in Xcode 6:`
[image: How I did in Xcode 6]

According to @gabbler's answer, I successfully export my file from device, and I made this tutorial with a picture, thanks to @gabbler again!
[image]

Comment: Also if you are into better tools for managing iOS app files, check out a program called iExplorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drag to the bottom and click the setting button, then click Download Container.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks! And I will make a tutorial with another picture!